# address search exclude special characters

Tags: java

The address can only contain letters, numbers, % and one dash (-) all other special characters are not allowed. The single dash (-) can only be positioned between 2 numbers. The % symbol can be positioned anywhere in the address and there can be multiple occurrences of it.

```
Valid:   1-10 Downing Street
Valid:   Downing Street 1-10
Valid:   Downing Street
Valid:   Downing%
Valid:   %Downing Street
Valid:   %Dow%ng Street
Invalid: -10 Downing Street
```

I am using Java Pattern and Matcher to validate the address. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: I had tried "[\\*|\\>|\\$|\\!|\\!|\\:|\\=|\\&|\\,|\\)|\\(|\\[|\\]]" to just exclude certain characters.

Comment: You should edit your question, and explain what you tried and why it's not what you want...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try  this regex:

```
"[%\\w][%\\w ]+( \\d+-?\\d+)?|(\\d+-?\\d+ )?[%\\w][%\\w ]+"
```

Comment: cheers that is exaclty what I asked for, a slight change to the requirements tho :-). Just letters are valid without numbers, i.e Downing Street.

Comment: tested "Downing Street".matches("\\w[\\w ]+ \\d+-?\\d+|\\d+-?\\d+ \\w[\\w ]+")); gives me false. you mean it's wrong?

Comment: "Downing Street" should give true. When i first entered my question I did not specify this.

Comment: Please could the regular expression be changed to also cater for allowing the % symbol to be positioned anywhere and to also allow for multiple occurrences?

Comment: Can you give me examples of what is valid (with %)?

Comment: Hi these are valid, 'Downing%', '%Downing Street', 'Downi% Str%', '%owning Street', 'Downing% 21' the rules around the % is very relaxed (it is optional, can occur a multpile number of times and can be positioned anywhere)